# Issue on changing background opacity on hover a box

Tags: css

I am working on the following demo. Why is the background transparency not functioning properly?

```
 .figure .caption-mask:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to remove opacity from the `.caption-mask` on hovering over `.figure` but it is not functioning correctly. Please try to hover over all side of the `.figure` to see the different result.

```css
.figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.figure .caption-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  transition: background .5s ease-out;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.figure .caption-mask:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.caption h3 {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.figure img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

.figure:hover img {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 text-center">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="figure">
          <img src="https://tsicloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/cloud.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">

          <div class="caption-mask"></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Test</h3>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
.figure .caption-mask:hover
```

to

```
.figure:hover .caption-mask
```

```css
.figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.figure .caption-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  transition: background .5s ease-out;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.figure:hover .caption-mask {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.caption h3 {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.figure img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

.figure:hover img {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 text-center">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="figure">
          <img src="https://tsicloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/cloud.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">

          <div class="caption-mask"></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Test</h3>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots connexo,